# How does bash and sh find python if it's not in $PATH?

Tags: bash, shell, python, path

How does the shell know where to find `python` when I don't have a `$PATH` variable set?

```bsh
$ env -i bash
bash-3.2$ env
PWD=/Users/cweber/projects/monorepo
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/env
bash-3.2$ which python
bash-3.2$ type python
python is /usr/bin/python
bash-3.2$ python -c 'print("hello")'
hello
```

The same works with `sh`. I'm on MacOS if it makes any difference.

Comment: Your PATH is not empty, try `echo "$PATH"`.

Comment: I believe that bash has hard coded values if not set.  Try: strings /bin/bash | grep /usr/bin

Comment: I'm guessing here (printing out `$PATH` will lead to better guesses), but `env -i` launches `bash` with an empty environment, but the system and user `.bashrc` are still loaded, which likely set `PATH` for you, albeit without critical expected env variables like `$HOME`, creating an unstable/unpredictable environment. So `$PATH` may have some garbage values in it, but it'll still be set. Also, perhaps related, if `$HOME` isn't set (and hence tilde `~`), `which` may act weird vs eg `type` https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580022/127971

Comment: Oof, `$PATH` is indeed still set; I thought `env -i` cleared it out, but clearly I was mistaken. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Start here (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) and follow the breadcrumbs.